# Chrome Packaged Apps Manifest - loading in jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm running into this error, I'm wondering if my manifest is setup correct.. or is there a better way to get jquery to execute.

Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

```
"sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "open.html"
    ]
    "content_security_policy":
        "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src https://ajax.googleapis.com"
  ],

}
```

//open.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="open.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the whole manifest? It seems that you are running a Chrome App, the new form of Packaged Apps.
Chrome Apps don't allow you to change the Content Security Policy. ([source](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html#what)) Therefore, you will have to download the jQuery files to your app's folder and reference them as local files.